# CSS outline getting covered by other elements

Tags: css

I have a grid of buttons and on hover/focus I want to display a outline around the button. The problem is the other buttons are covering the element's outline. How do I make the outline display on top of the other buttons? I'd prefer to not use pseudo elements.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  width: 12rem;
  place-items: stretch;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
} 

.tile:where(:hover, :focus, :focus-visible, :focus-within) {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <button class="tile">1</button>
  <button class="tile">2</button>
  <button class="tile">3</button>
  <button class="tile">4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting z-index to the `.tile:where(:hover, :focus, :focus-visible, :focus-within)` to selector just like below.

```
.tile:where(:hover, :focus, :focus-visible, :focus-within) {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Working example is below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  width: 12rem;
  place-items: stretch;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
} 

.tile:where(:hover, :focus, :focus-visible, :focus-within) {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <button class="tile">1</button>
  <button class="tile">2</button>
  <button class="tile">3</button>
  <button class="tile">4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use z-index of more than 1 please and add a working demo for your answer. It makes easier to understand and I will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

User a `z-index` on your `...:hover... {...}` (etc.)  rule. Value `1` is enough for the isolated example below, but you might have to set it to a higher value in more complex situations.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  width: 12rem;
  place-items: stretch;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
} 

.tile:where(:hover, :focus, :focus-visible, :focus-within) {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <button class="tile">1</button>
  <button class="tile">2</button>
  <button class="tile">3</button>
  <button class="tile">4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "border" property.

```
.tile:where(:hover, :focus, :focus-visible, :focus-within) { border: 5px solid blue; }
```